# tipo de dato para coordenadas en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

buenas estoy tratando de crear dos campos en una tabla de sql server los cuales cada una va a almacenar longitud y latitud respectivamente sin embargo tengo la duda de que tipo de dato usar al principio pensaba en usar decimal pero no me deja ingresar números negativos alguna alternativa?

Comment: Te invito a que des un recorrido para que sepas como [preguntar y contestar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour),

Answer (score 3):

A partir de SQL 2008 ya puedes usar un tipo geográfico, aunque también puedes usar decimales, [6 dígitos después del punto para mayor precisión]DECIMAL(9,6).

```
    --Ejemplo de declaracion de variable de un punto geografico
    DECLARE @g geography;  
    SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);  
    SELECT @g.Lat;  

--declaracion en columna

[Localizacion] [geography] NULL

--consulta
select  
  [Localizacion].Lat as Latitud,  [Localizacion].Long as Longitud
   from [TablaLocalizacionEntidades]
```

Saludos